# How can I open another websites in django?

Tags: python, django, web

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>Projects</h3>
    </div>
    {% if list_of_projects %}
        {% for project in list_of_projects %}
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{ project.project_logo }}" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h2>{{ project.project_name }}</h2>
                        <h4>{{ project.project_details }}</h4>

                        <!-- Visit Link -->
                        <a href="{{ project.link }}" target="_blank"
                           class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Visit Link</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% cycle '' '' '' '' '' '<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>' %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Let the url saved in the database is - "www.github.com".

When the user click on "Visit Link" it should redirect it to the url saved in the database.
But instead of redirecting it to the url saved in the database it is redirecting it to the (http://127.0.0.1:8000/all_projects/www.github.com)

[Redirected Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFaTC.png)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: what does the link look like when you inspect the element?

Comment: I think it's because of how it is saved in your db. try this: "//{{ project.link }}"

Comment: @JonasGiuro Thanks! It worked.

Comment: No problem, I'm happy it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to write url in Django Template, but mostly used ones are:

Absolute url: https://www.google.com

Relative url: `/users/list/`

Relative url can also be given from `url tag` if it is defined in urls.py.

In urls.py

```
url(r'^users/list/$', views.users, name='users')
```

In templates.py

```
{% url 'users' %}
```

Url tag converts the relative url to full url path by appending with base url

http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/list/

However, if only string is provided in href without `http://(or https://)` or url tag then the string is appended to the current url path and in this case becomes http://127.0.0.1:8000/all_projects/www.github.com

Since, redirection should be done to third party url (www.github.com) either use `https://` as suggested by @Exprator

or as I prefer save full url (https://www.github.com) in the database

Comment: It's easier to just use "//" instead of http or https, that way the browser will pick the right one according to the current site.

Comment: For convenience it is easy, but my suggestion is to save the full url in database instead of adding // or http in template